# How to show third column according to first, yet keep second column unchanged

Tags: awk

I have text file like this example:

```
a | 0 | 11

a | 0 | 22

a | 1 | 22

a | 1 | 22
```

I am using this command:

```
awk -F"|" '{ sum[$1"|"$2]+=$3 } END { for (user in sum) printf "%10d |%12.2f\n",user,sum[user] }' myfile
```

which produces a result

```
0 |       33.00
0 |       44.00
```

My expected result

```
a | 0 | 33

a | 1 | 44
```

Comment: You are trying to use an integer format specifier (`%10d`) to print strings (`$1"|"$2`)

Comment: are all these spaces and empty lines in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `printf` statement:

```
awk -F'|' '
    {sum[$1"|"$2]+=$3}
    END{for (i in sum){printf "%s| %d\n",i,sum[i]}}
' file
```

Output:

```
a | 0 | 33
a | 1 | 44
```

---

This would also be a pretty easy task for SQL:

```
csvsql -d '|' -H --tables t \
--query 'select trim(a),b,sum(c) from t group by a,b' \
<(grep -v '^$' file)
```

Output:

```
trim(a),b,sum(c)
a,0,33
a,1,44
```

Add `| tail -n+2` to remove the header line, and `| csvformat -D '|'` to change delimiter to `|`.

Output:

```
a|0|33
a|1|44
```

Comment: Thanks for fixup